# Unity game in edit the scene mode all of a sudden became incredibly slow/"laggy"

Tags: unity, lag

So I recently have been working on a game. So far I have very few assets in the game, which are a point light, a piece of terrain (which is textured), a player controller and a tree. Everything was going well until I put the tree in the scene. I made  tree and started to add some branches I got to about 8 branches, and then I added 35 leafs. Then the edit scene started to become laggy.
When I played the game it was running perfectly. But as soon as I changed the scene back to edit mode it became laggy again. I then deleted the tree to see if that would solve the problem but it seems to have done nothing at all. I would really appreciate if someone could explain why the edit scene is becoming laggy even though there are only a few assets within the game.

Thanks, Nova

Comment: Sometimes with unity you just don't know! I had a bug that prevented me from renaming folders... It has happened to me twice and each time I had to reinstall unity. Maybe give that a try.

Comment: Just try to nail the problem using divide and conquer. Try to find a functioning state e.g. remove all objects (or even start a new project and export -> import all assets). Then test only removing half of the objects and iterate until it breaks. When  you have a repeatable problem (you know that by doing a well defined thing it breaks and by undoing it it works). When you have that you will receive answers which are constructive.

Comment: If you are on Textured wire mode, try going to textured. It worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the solution:

When I was making a game, I have faced a similar problem.
Either in edit mode or game mode, it is the same.
If the camera is looking at a complicated texture, it will lag.
Maybe you are looking at a complicated texture in the edit mode, and the camera in play mode is looking at a non-complicated texture.
I was making a fps game, and when I stood on a particular box and looked down, it became glitchy.

Hope that helps!